# Glut: same callback for multiple windows, determine who is calling

Tags: callback, glut

I have a project done with Glut where most subwindows have the same behavior, except the dont quite exactly display the same thing (images for now).

I want to reuse code as much as possible, and decided to use a single callback per event, used by all windows for the specific event.

Is their from inside the callback a way to determine which subwindow received the event ?

The goal would be to do something like this (since a pointer to a member method is forbidden) :

```
MyWindow* window1;
MyWindow* window2;
MyWindow* window3;

...

void callbacksReshape(int w, int h)
{
    if("window 1")
        window1->reshape(int w, int h);
    if("window 2")
        window2->reshape(int w, int h);
    if("window 3")
        window3->reshape(int w, int h);
}
```

Thanks all for your answers !

EDIT : I know about `glutGetWindow`, the question is: does Glut calls `glutSetWindow` before calling the callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure `glutGetWindow` would give the right ID, but after a bit of testing it seems to work (Mac OSX 10.8.2 and Fedora 3.4.6-2.fc17.x86_64 ):

```
void disp()
{ return; }

void idle()
{ return; }

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    GLuint id_fenetre = glutGetWindow();
    printf("%d has moved\n", id_fenetre);
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);

    GLuint id;
    char *title = (char*)calloc(255, sizeof(char));

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        GLuint id = glutCreateWindow("");
        sprintf(title, "%d", id);
        glutSetWindow(id);
        glutDisplayFunc(&disp);
        glutReshapeFunc(&reshape);
        glutSetWindowTitle(title);

        printf("Window %d created", id);
    }

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps someone !